# PostgreSQL: Returning of an Update into variable/temp table

Tags: postgresql

I have an `update` statement with `returning` statement.

What I want is to put the result into a variable or temp table.

```
update my_table
set something = 'x'
where id ...
returning *;
```

I tried to that using the `execute` statement and e.g. `returning row_to_json(my_table.*)` but the variable, off cause, only contains the first row returned from the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE with the UPDATE-RETURNING statement in it, then use that in the INSERT:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (i int, j int);
CREATE TEMP TABLE u (i int, j int);
INSERT INTO u VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3);
```

---

```
WITH updated AS (
  UPDATE u
  SET i = i * 10
  WHERE i < 3
  RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO t
SELECT *
FROM updated;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/63e08/1)